# Gas molecules / photons interaction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics

I've encountered a [comment on a Physics SE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/138103/how-do-gas-molecules-constantly-bounce-without-losing-energy#comment284599_138103):

> ... there are no perfectly elastic collisions between atoms and molecules. Some part of the energy/momentum will be converted into photons...

My question is about the *consumption* of a photon by a gas molecule. Would it be true to suppose, that a "free fleeting" molecule can absorb a photon of an arbitrary wavelength, thus increasing its kinetic energy?..

Do you think this behaviour complies with quantum mechanics / has been modelled / calculated theoretically?

Did you meet any mention of experimental approval of such behaviour?..

I guess it must be so, simply because our body feels heat from infrared light - obviously atoms / molecules start to vibrate faster. But I failed to google any information particularly regarding real gases, like noble Helium or Agron...

URL, if available, would be appreciated :-)

I'm asking because I'm working on 2D simulation of real gas molecules behaviour at STP, and need to understand if I could ignore photons, or rather should add them to the simulation.

Comment: “a "free fleeting" molecule can absorb a photon ..., thus *increasing* its kinetic energy?” Depends from the relative direction of motion of both particles. Coming in opposite direction the photon will decrease the kinetic energy of the molecules. See [laser cooling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_cooling).

Comment: Thanks HolgerFiedler, this really helped me to understand better. Another question arised though after reading: laser (doppler) cooling involves atom's "excited" state, then re-emitting a photon. What about the low-energy photons, like IR - seems they can't be absorbed by a "free fleeting" noble gas atom. Thus, energy will be leaking (to space). Thus, the real gas pressure remains stable in a long run only due Earth/Sun re-heating it (STP). My understanding is that we can't actually name a real gas with its photons a "thermodynamical equillibrium system" - it seems to be a one-way process.

Comment: .... I mean, that if the colliding gas molecules emit a weak "black body" radiation, photons of all wavelengths (not 100% elastic collisions), then part of those photons, the colder ones, wouldn't be able to interact with the gas - as far as I understood. Thus, a real gas in STP is a system, consuming "hotter" photons from the surrounding world, and "producing" "colder" photons in exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Although a photon has momentum, one can ignore this at STP for light (or UV or IR) because the momentum of the gas molecules is much larger at room temperature.

Comment: Thanks Pieter! I think I will ignore the photons in my Simulation, as their energy (and momentums) at STP are way less important than Van der Waals forces effects. OK, but while thinking it all over, I started to suspect that we probably shouldn't call the real gas "an equillibrium", in fact it must cool down by itself - see above. If I'm not mistaking, this perfectly illustrates enthropy :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have photons with sufficiently high energy (extreme ultraviolet) they would ionize atoms, and the resulting high energy electrons would increase the kinetic energy of the atoms i.e. the temperature of the gas correspondingly.

In case of a gas consisting of molecules, infrared radiation can excite rotational and/or vibrational states. This energy could be transferred to  kinetic energy as well through elastic collisions.